# Repath joined tables in ArcMap 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have an .mxd with a couple dozen layers each pointing to the same feature class and joined table. Each layer is symbolized by attributes in the joined table and have definition queries using the joined table.

In this year's update of the database, our client has requested that we **change the name of the joined table** - new records have been added and edited, but the **schema is unchanged**. And since the customer is always right, the sales guys said "of course!"

Now, since the table name has changed, everything is broken. **Is there a way to repath all of these joins and definition queries to the new joined table name?** "Set Data Source(s)" does not appear to do what I need it to here.

Comment: Are you just worried about broken links and getting the DQs to work? As opposed to broken symbology and labeling rules.

Comment: any/all of the above.  I can update everything (reestablish joins, fix labelling, DQs etc) individually but I'm hoping to streamline it by somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join is not just a path, it is a saved relationship of a sort. So, no from recent experience, I believe you have to remove the bad join, rejoin to the new-named file for each layer. Then, you will probably have to rebuild the DQs, because it is difficult to get ArcMap to honor any settings about fully qualified names, so your old Join table name may be part of the FQ name for each field.  If some layers are similar, you could fix one and copy it, then change it as needed. If possible, try to fix this before the old file is gone. You can then use your unbroken layers as references because their symbology will still be viewable and their DQs will be working.

Comment: Yeah that's what i figured...thanks for confirming.